# Smoothly concatenating sine waves from input

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

Last month, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006591/how-to-concatenate-sine-waves-without-phase-jumps) about how to concatenate sine waves WHEN you are generating them, but now I've faced a different situation where I will generate a sine and make it continue from the end of another sine I did not generate.

My solution was based on the second answer to my previous question, compute the hilbert transform, then, calculate the angle with numpy.angle and normalize it by adding 90, and generating the next sine from there. It works, but only when the unit of my frequency value is 0 or 5, otherwise, the waves doesn't match and I have no clue why.

```
from scipy.signal import hilbert
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1024
t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
freq = 5.0

c = np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t + 0.0)
c2 = np.angle(hilbert(c), True)  # in degrees

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(c)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)

phase = c2[-1] + 90

c3 = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * freq * t + np.deg2rad(phase))

plt.grid()
plt.plot(c3)
plt.show()
```

Frequency: 5.0

[image: Frequency of 5.0, match]

Frequency: 5.8

[image: Frequency of 5.8, miss]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what your exact problem scope is.  In the previous question, in a comment which spawned this followup question, you said:

> If I don't have the generation equation ( say, I've got a chunk from mic ) what would be the approach?

Does this mean the data is not necessarily a sine wave?  Is it noisy?  Is it of varying magnitude?  You mention DSP: are you doing the processing in real time, or can the analysis take as long as needed?

---

If it is a clean sine wave of known magnitude, it is relatively easy to extract the phase from the end of the signal, to allow a smooth continuation.

The phase is `sin⁻¹(y/mag)`.  There are two inputs to `sin(angle)`, which result in the value `y/mag`, one for where `sin(angle)` is increasing with increasing `angle`, and one for when it is decreasing. By looking at the previous point, we can determine which one we need.

```
def ending_phase(c, mag):
    angle = math.asin(c[-1] / mag)
    if c[-2] > c[-1]:
        angle = np.pi - angle
    return angle
```

From the phase of the last point, and the phase of the second last point, we can extrapolate the phase for the next point.

```
def next_phase(c, mag):
    ph1 = ending_phase(c[:-1], mag)
    ph2 = ending_phase(c, mag)
    return 2 * ph2 - ph1
```

Passing the previous chunk to `next_phase()` computes the phase argument required to smoothly continue the chunk.

```
N = 1024
t = np.linspace(0, 1, N)

mag = 1.2
freq = 5.2
phase = 2.2
c1 = mag * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t + phase)

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(c1)


freq = 3.8
phase = next_phase(c1, mag)

c2 = mag * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t + phase)
plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(c2)


c3 = np.concatenate((c1, c2))
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(c3)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks AJ (again), I'm afraid my intention to make things simple made me sound vague, I will try to not do it again.

Answer (score 2):

When the values at the beginning and the end of the time interval do not agree, boundary effects appear, distorting the Hilbert transform. (Recall that the Fourier transform reacts poorly to discontinuities.) This can be seen by plotting the end of `c2`: `plt.plot(c2[-200:] + 90)`: notice the distortion toward the end, the curve is supposed to rise with constant slope.

[image: bad]

You'll get better results by stepping back one period from the edge of the time window:

```
phase = c2[-1 - int(N//freq)] + 90
```

I tried with frequency 5.8: the beginning of second curve matches the end of the first.

[image: match]

Comment: Assuming I don't have the exact frequency of the first wave (which is the case in my problem) this method will not work, right?

Comment: And assuming that I don't have a reliable way of getting the exact frequency (which... may be the case).

Comment: Also, I did some test with your very welcome solution, and, strangely enough, when I tested with frequency = 18.0, the graph was slightly broken.

Comment: The jumps in `np.angle(hilbert(c))` give a pretty good handle on the frequency (they occur once per period).  With high frequency, perhaps stepping back one period is not enough to avoid the boundary effects... Also, perhaps this is a silly suggestion, but why not just match the end/start values of two waves? Find whatever value of the second fits the end of the first wave, and start from there. Check the direction of increase as well.

Comment: This is not a silly suggestion, I'm just trying to solve this problem, so I can learn and make a good product for my client, that was the solution I came up with, also I'm new to DSP, if you do know some better method, feel free to point me the direction.